# How to execute sudo as user with root password

Tags: linux, sudo

How can I configure Linux to see the prompt for the root password if `Sam` try to execute the following command: `$ sudo mkdir /opt/test`?

If `Sam` is part of sudoers, the terminal ask for the user password not for the root password.

Comment: This is not a computer programming question. Questions like this belong on unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /etc/sudoers, add this line:

```
Defaults rootpw
```

Make sure you use visudo for editing this file. For more information, you can check the [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos)